# How to add Unicode characters from MySql Command to database

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

i am adding Unicode character data to database from MySQL insert command it is showing question mark in output webpage.But when i am adding this data from admin panel it is showing correctly.I want to add data from mysql command so please help.